# How to turn a weighted edgelist into an adjacency matrix in r

Tags: r, igraph, adjacency-matrix, network-analysis, edge-list

I have a weighted edge list and I want to convert it into an adjacency matrix.
Is there a simple code I can use to do this?

The data looks like this:

```
  From To    Weight
1    a  a 0.3274570
2    b  a 0.7188648
3    a  b 0.1097450
4    b  b 0.9054419
```

Here is replication code:

```
edgelist <- setNames(cbind(expand.grid(letters[1:2], letters[1:2]), runif(4)), c("From", "To", "Weight"))
edgelist
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to use `get.adjacency` from the `igraph` package.

```
library(igraph)
mygraph <- graph.data.frame(edgelist)
get.adjacency(mygraph, sparse = FALSE, attr='Weight')
#          a         b
#a 0.3274570 0.1097450
#b 0.7188648 0.9054419
```

While it is certainly possible to simply transform the data to a matrix, it might be helpful to be prepared to use the rest of this package's features.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: I seem to get 3 "extra quadrants" of zeroes using this method? On the resulting matrix, both axes contain all entries of "From" and "To". In my case, each entry is unique. May need another step to subset it correctly...

Answer (score 1):

```
as.matrix(tidyr::spread(edgelist, "To", "Weight")[-1])
```

Comment: The resulting matrix has no row names. Just 1-n (number of rows).